# java program for not hard coding the file path of sd card android emulator

Tags: java, android-emulator

program in java android, How to not hard code the file path in sd card android emulator i.e program in java to accept the file from the user to sd card android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

to get the path to a folder

```
path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("foldername");
```